# regression model with arma errors: forecasting the residuals

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, kalman-filter

Suppose I estimate the following model:

$$
y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_t + \eta_t
$$
where $\eta_t$ is an AR(1) model, say. I can do that with `forecast::Arima()` as follows:

```
#fake data
n <- 100
x <- 1:n
y <- 1 -3*x + arima.sim(model = list(ar = .1), n)

# estimate model
mod <- forecast::Arima(y, order = c(1,0,0), xreg = x)
mod
```

How do I forecast
$$
\hat{\eta}_{t+1} := y_{t+1} - \left[ \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_{t+1} \right]
$$
assuming both $y_{t+1}$ and $x_{t+1}$ are unknown (so I can't use $x_{t+1}$)?

Does [`forecast.forecast_ARIMA()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/forecast/man/forecast.Arima.html) give me the Kalman forecasts (the documentation does not say)? If so, maybe I could do some algebra to the Kalman recursions.

Another idea: extract the residuals and the estimated ARMA model for $\eta_t$, and then perform the Kalman recursions on the residuals.

Comment: Could you give a reference for `forecast.forecast_ARIMA()`? Also, conceptually the forecast of the error is simply the one obtained from the AR(1) model. Given that, are you interested in the R implementation, or what is the question?

Comment: If your predictor $x$ is unknown to you in the future, then you may have bigger problems than forecasting the ARIMA errors (as in, often the contribution from the regression is orders of magnitude larger than that of the autocorrelated residuals). You may want to make "reasonable" assumptions on $x_{t+1}$, possibly run a scenario forecast. Can you explain the underlying problem?

Comment: @StephanKolassa the underlying problem is motivated by cointegration. Once you have the fixed betas, you turn that into a cointegrating vector $\boldsymbol{w}$, and you model that combination of levels as a (usually univariate) ARMA process. I think maybe the move is writing everything in VECM form.